# I am doing the Tutorial for the Android

Tags: android, import

I am going through the tutorial Android application programming and by the end of the "responded to actions" section [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) I am having issues with the R class and its methods. IU believe its something to do with my imports.

Can someone please list the imports that they have at that point.

here are mine:

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Comment: Delete `import android.R;` then clean and rebuild your project

Comment: @codeMagic please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.java` is a generated file that refers to resource IDs (such as ids from layouts, strings, styles, dimensions, menu, etc).

Looking at that action button tutorial suggests you're generating your own resources and not using androids.

This is absolutely fine, and required to build awesome android apps, but it means that the ID for these resources wont exist in `android.R` but rather `com.yourandroidpackage.R`, where `yourandroidpackage` is the top level package name for your application

Verify that there are no errors in your xml files, clean your project, rebuild, and try replacing `import android.R;` with `import com.yourandroidpackage.R`.

Comment: I have added the "import com.example.myfirstapp.R" line but the IDE, Eclipse in this case, says that it is an unused import. Also, after deleting the previous import and cleaning my code says that all the references to "R" in both my "Activity" say its and error. So both the Activities dont recognize which R to look at.

Answer (score 0):

try this **import yourpackagename.R** instead of **import android.R**.

thanks

Comment: No, not required. The OP is having the issue at the Activity class so there's no need to import project's R resource. Only needs to import it if it's an external class.

Answer (score 0):

Delete import android.R; then clean and rebuild your project. You may need to change that to `import yourPackage.R` but it should be done automatically after cleaning and rebuilding, depending on your IDE. Having the Android `resource import` won't allow the app to recognize *your* `resource` `id`s.

You will also want to make sure that you have absolutely no errors in *any* xml files including your `manifest.xml`. If you do have any errors in `resource` files then the file won't be generated correctly.